# Segmentation fault when using pipe

Tags: c, fork, pipe, ipc

I'm doing assignment that ask to sum two arrays using 10 processes in parallel, so I write this code, and I'm used pipe to IPC between parent and it's child , but it's give me segmentation fault , when it want to read from pipe.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
struct s {
int * x ;
int max , min ;
} ;
void sum(int *a , int *b , struct s w , int min , int max , int pipe)
{
    int i ;
    for(i = min ; i < max ; i++)
    {
        *(w.x+i) = *(a+i)+*(b+i) ; 
    }
    write(pipe , w , sizeof(w)) ;
}
int main()
{
    int i ,min = 0 ,max = 1 ;
    int a[11] = {1,1,1,10,1,1,1,1,1,1,1} ; 
    int b[11] = {1,1,1,10,1,1,1,1,1,1,1} ;
    int c[11]; 
    int fd[2] ;
    int j ; 
    pipe(fd) ; 
    for(i =  0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
    {
        int pid = fork();
        if(pid == 0)
        {
            struct s w ;
            w.max = max ;
            w.min = min ;
            *w.x = c[0] ;
            close(fd[0]) ; 
            sum(a,b,w,min , max , fd[1]);
            printf("Done %d \n" , i);
            exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            min++;max++;
        }
    }
    struct s w ; 
    for(j = 0 ; j < 10 ; j++)
    {
        //segmentation fault !!
        read(fd[0] , w ,sizeof(struct s)) ;
        for(i =  w.min ; i < w.max ; i++)
        {
            printf("[%d] --> %d \n" ,i , *(w.x+i) ) ;
        }
    }   
    return 0; 
}
```

any idea ?

Comment: You should be passing `&w` to `read`; not `w`.

Comment: How did that ever compile? What compiler silently converts a structure instance to a pointer? I just can't.

Comment: You might like to always switch on all warnings (`-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` for gcc), and fix your code until none show up anymore.

Answer (score 2):

read() second parameter requires an address. Use & operator for the address of `w`.

```
read(fd[0] , &w ,sizeof(struct s)) ;
```

Comment: well , it's still give me the same problem !